# Facebook API - App using Oauth to update status of page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have built an app using the PHP Facebook SDK.  It allows users to authenticate my app with facebook OAth so that they can update their status' via my App.  This works great, however a lot of my users have business pages and they want to update the status on their business page not their main personal feed.  How is this possible?  Below is what I have so far.

```
if ($status != ''){

                    try {
                        $parameters = array(
                            'message' => "$status"/*,
                            'picture' => $_POST['picture'],
                            'link' => $_POST['link'],
                            'name' => $_POST['name'],
                            'caption' => $_POST['caption'],
                            'description' => $_POST['description']*/
                        );

                        //add the access token to it
                        $parameters['access_token'] = $access_token;

                        //build and call our Graph API request
                        $newpost = $facebook->api(
                            '/me/feed',
                            'POST',
                            $parameters
                        );

                        $success['status'] = "$xml->status";
                        $xml2 = new XMLGenerator($success, 'facebook','status');
                        $returnData = $xml2->output;                            

                        $returnData = APIResponse::successResponse('200', "$xml->status");

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $returnData = APIResponse::errorResponse('400', 'Facebook Error: '.$e);     
                    }
```

I assume I would have to change '/me/feed'?  but to what?  What is they have multiple pages how would my app know which page to post to?

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute `me` with the `PAGE_ID` to post to a page e.g., /013857894/feed. Make sure that you have completed the OAuth process with the `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions. You can learn more at the link below:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#statuses

If the user has multiple Pages then you will first need to give them some way of selecting which page they want to post to. You can find out which Facebook Pages a given user is the administrator of by calling `/me/accounts` for that user. You can find out more about this approach in the Connections section of this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/